# Activity stack keeps resetting upon launching the app for the first time

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin, reset

I'm building an app for Android via Xamarin, and I've come across a strange bug that only occurs the first time the app is launched. The app contains a moderate of state information, but the goal is that it should be sufficient to keep in memory for short amounts of time (eg, if the user receives a phone call, the app should restore properly once the phone call is complete) without needing to persist its state information.

The first time around, I transfer the app to the device, unpack it and install it. When I open the app for the first time, it all seems to work fine until I hit the 'home' button, and then return to the app by tapping its icon in the 'Apps' menu. When I do, the app doesn't appear to have actually terminated, but the entire Activity stack has been reset and it displays the default Activity again.

However, if I close the app, and completely terminate it before opening it again, then it operates completely fine as expected.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? It seems strange that an app exhibits different behaviour on its initial launch than its subsequent launches after that. Thanks!

Comment: can you post the manifest file? im curious to see the activity configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be in an answer as the comment field does not allow this much text, but I have some counter questions to your question, which I may help to clear up what is going on with your app.

Using the `Home` button on Android does not terminate the application, but rather it just puts the application into the background. The `Back` button however will terminate the `Activity` or call `Finish()` on it resulting in a slightly different behavior.

In both cases whatever you put into the `Bundle` in `OnSaveInstanceState` is what you get in the `Bundle` when you return to the app, if it has been terminated in the meantime, in `OnCreate`.

> (..) the goal is that it should be sufficient to keep in memory for short amounts of time (eg, if the user receives a phone call, the app should restore properly once the phone call is complete) without needing to persist its state information.

How do you propose to do this? Android can at any time terminate your application when it is not being shown in the foreground. Hence saving state in `OnSaveInstanceState` is crucial to any app wanting to persist some kind of state. You cannot rely on the assumption that it might not get terminated, and whether it gets terminated is different from device to device, as they differ in how much heap space they have, how much RAM they have etc. So you will experience different behavior on different devices.

> However, if I close the app, and completely terminate it before opening it again, then it operates completely fine as expected.

How exactly are you persisting state, since it only works when you terminate your application, what exactly do you do?

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! Your answer pointed me in the right direction.

After taking both the 'back' button and 'home' button behaviour into consideration, I tried installing a separate (non-Xamarin) app the same way and discovered it behaved the exact same way. Turns out it's actually a standard behaviour on all of the Samsung devices I was testing on.

Not just that, but it wasn't actually saving the activity and restoring it, but it was spawning 2 instances of the same activity, the second ignoring the restore state of the first one, hence my confusion about how it was persisting the memory.